# Using regex to split()

Tags: regex, string, actionscript-3, split

I've been trying to get a regular expression to work for my code for a while and am wondering if anyone knows a better way.

I've got a big chunk of text to parse and want to split it into an array based on the lines. This would be straightforward, right? Using regex:

```
var re:RegExp = /\n/;    
arr = content.split(re);
```

Easy. But I also want to only split on lines that do not have a space after them. I figured I'd use the \S character to match anything with a non-space character after the \n.

```
var re:RegExp = /\n\S/;    
arr = content.split(re);
```

However, this now removes the first letter of every line I'm splitting (because it's matching those letters).

What's the best way to:

1. Ignore the spaces by using a caret (I tried something like `/\n^\' '/` but no luck)?
2. Not lose that `\S` character when splitting the string into an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use lookahead in your pattern (so \S symbol won't be consumed as a split separator):

```
var re:RegExp = /\n(?=\S)/;    
arr = content.split(re);
```

Comment: I appreciate your solution! This answer works really well.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to [raina77ow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1229023/raina77ow) answer (using positive lookahead with `\S`), you can also use a negative lookahead with `\s`:

```
var re:RegExp = /\n(?!\s)/;    
arr = content.split(re);
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]